# Too much RAM after load scene textures in high resolution

Tags: 3d-view, performance, hardware

My current project contains many object with 2K and 4K textures. I don't have problem with RAM during render, but only when I open this scene. It take more than 20GB and it take long time to display. I understand that Blender need load all textures, but is there some method to optimize it? I even don't need see these textures in the viewport. I tried several things:

- Viewport textures limit size to 2048 had no effect
- Change Image Display method had no effect
- Show object only as viewframe had no effect (object restriction)

It would be nice to have some solution for proxy (low res) textures for viewport and high res textures for render, because I can not use smaller textures during render.

My last option is a make some script to rename folder with textures, so Blender will not find it and show it pink :) And before render repair paths back.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137121/whats-the-most-lightweight-format-for-textures/137129#137129 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33206/view-memory-usage/67039#67039

Answer (score 0):

So my solution to complete this project was:

1. I prepared same lowres textures in the different directory for example:
   `D:\MyProject\MyTextures` for highres and `D:\MyProject\MyTexturesLow` for lowres
2. I used simple script for change name folder from `MyTextures` to `MyTexturesLow` and opposite
3. I renamed textures folder with script before open scene and switch back before render

It is only solution which save my project :) You can rename folder without script of course.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the script in order to help future visitors?

Comment: Of course, it was simple "os.rename" command from python, something like this:

`import bpy`
`import os`

`os.rename( "highres path", 'highres path_TMP' )`
`os.rename( "lowres path", "highres path" )`
`os.rename( "highres path_TMP", "lowres path" )`

where path is "D:\SomeTextures"